# In Good Omens, why would anybody want to buy MEALS?

Tags: good-omens

Neil Gaiman explains **CHOW** (**MEAL**'s predecessor) as:

> CHOW contained spun, plaited, and woven protein molecules, capped and
>   coded, carefully designed to be ignored by even the most ravenous
>   digestive tract enzymes; no-cal sweeteners; mineral oils replacing
>   vegetable oils; fibrous materials, colorings, and flavorings. The end
>   result was a foodstuff almost indistinguishable from any other except
>   for two things. Firstly, the price, which was slightly higher, and
>   secondly, the nutritional content, which was roughly equivalent to
>   that of a Sony Walkman.

As for **MEALS**, he says:

> MEALS was CHOW with added sugar and fat. The theory was that if you
>   ate enough MEALS you would a) get very fat, and b) die of
>   malnutrition.

Now, I can understand someone buying **CHOW** because they could eat lots and lots and still not get fat (Gaiman calls it the "*ultimate diet food*"). But why would they buy **MEALS** when it provides neither nutrition, nor reduces weight?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the joke here is the MEALS already exist. They're the microwave meals available in every supermarket in every country in the world and they work pretty much as described.

Comment: Marketing.  It covers a multitude of sins.

Comment: Because they taste nicer.

Answer (score 9):

It seemed to me like a joke about fad diets and how they don't really help at all, so the MEALs are the logical conclusion to that concept: food that just doesn't do anything at all except cost you money.